# stat() is returning that existing files don't exist (C)

Tags: c, system-calls, stat

I'm having a really weird issue that I can't seem to solve.

I am trying to stat the files in a directory in my C program but valid files are returning -1 (the file doesn't exist). The thing is, the files are valid and do have some data in them.

Another interesting thing is that the default directories . and .. are returning 0.

Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <langinfo.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int c, char *v[])
{
    int len;
    struct dirent *pDirent;
    DIR *pDir;
    char buffer[500] = {'\0'};
    char *files[10000];
    struct stat statbuf;
    int i = 0;
    int status;

    if (c < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: testprog <dirname>\n");
        return 1;
    }
    pDir = opendir(v[1]);
    if (pDir == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open directory '%s'\n", v[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    // http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstatat.html

    while ((pDirent = readdir(pDir)) != NULL)
    {

        strcpy(buffer, (const char *)pDirent->d_name);
        files[i] = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
        strcpy(files[i], buffer);
        printf("buffer: %s \n", buffer);
        if (stat(pDirent->d_name, &statbuf) == -1)
        {
            perror("stat");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        status = stat(pDirent->d_name, &statbuf);
        printf("status: %d \n", status);
        i++;
    }
    closedir(pDir);

    return 0;
}
```

The output when I run the stat command on the files within the directory is below:

```
buffer: test2
status: -1
buffer: .
status: 0
buffer: tset3
status: -1
buffer: ..
status: 0
buffer: test1
status: -1
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Pulling my hair out here.

Comment: `pDirent->d_name` is the file name, not the file full path

Comment: You need to print both `pDirent->d_name` and `strerror(errno)` after the call to `stat` that _fails_ - you're only doing that after the call that _succeeds_.  I can't think of a good reason why two consecutive `stat` calls with the same arguments should have different results, but without knowing what `pDirent->d_name` and `strerror(errno)` are, we're guessing in the dark.

Comment: How can `status: -1` ever be printed when you exit if that's the case?

Comment: Thanks, Jean-Francois. That's exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate the directory name with "/" and the dentry name and pass that to `stat` or you need to call `fstatat` with the directory's `fd` and the dentry name (or you need to be in the directory you're reading so that each dentry name is simultaneously a correct relative name).